# JQuery Requests overlaps in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery

Hi I have dynamically added functionality like adding a customer to a customer list appear in mouse over event .  it has add new list item and once the user clicks it a textbox appears and once the user enters valid content it adds the newly entered item to the list saves it and displays the newly added thing with a tick. and when a user click on already ticked item it deletes from the list .

when i implement this functionality locally we can add a customer to many lists from one try . but when i upload the application and try it it saves a new customer group but when i trying to add more from a one shot it only added the last one. the previously added customers key is going with the request .  if the customer s key already available it deletes the customer from the group which already being added . this works more like facebook's friend list which you can find in friends page we can add friends to different lists.

is there a way to synchronize jquery ajax requests . can any one help?

```
$('.newcustomerlist').live("keypress",function (event) {
    var element_id = $('.custitem').attr('id');
    var customer_key = null;
    var url_key = null;
    if (element_id != null) {
        customer_key  = element_id.split('#')[0]
        url_key = element_id.split('#')[1]
    } else {
        url_key = $(this).attr("id");
    }

    if(event.which == '13') {
        var cust_list_name = $(this).val().trim();
        var val = (/^[a-zA-Z ]*[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/).test(cust_list_name);
        if(val){
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "/addcustomerfromhere/",
                data : "cust_list_name=" + cust_list_name,
                success : function (msg) {
                    new_customer_key  = msg.customer_key ;
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "/addcustomertolist/",
                        data : "url_key=" + url_key + "&customer_key =" + new_customer_key ,
                        success : function (data) {
                            $("ul.custlist").prepend("<li id="+ new_customer_key  + "#"+ url_key + " class='custitem addedtocust'><span>" + msg.cust_list_name + "</span></li>");
                            $(".title").show();
                        },
                        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $.notify({message: 'Apologies. Our servers are busy at this moment. Please try again later.', type: 'error'});
                        }
                    });
                },
                error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $.notify({message: 'Apologies. Our servers are busy at this moment. Please try again later.', type: 'error'});
                }
            });
        $(".addnew").show()
        $(".newtext").hide()
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add this to the ajax options:

```
async:false
```

Comment: could you provide an example of sorts in jsfiddle or somewhere for me to better understand what the real problem is.